# User "system" cannot list all services in the cluster

Tags: authentication, permissions, openshift

I'm new to openshift.  I'm trying to work through some basic install options.  First I was able to download and run the vagrant image.  When I did that I was able to login and see several projects and containers running.  Next I tried the binary install.  So I downloaded openshift origin server v1.3.1 untared it and ran the following:

sudo openshift start

It seems that openshift started, but I did notice a few questionable lines in the output as follows:

```
W1103 09:06:47.360850    4647 start_master.go:272] Warning: assetConfig.loggingPublicURL: Invalid value: "": required to view aggregated container
 logs in the console, master start will continue.
W1103 09:06:47.360906    4647 start_master.go:272] Warning: assetConfig.metricsPublicURL: Invalid value: "": required to view cluster metrics in t
he console, master start will continue.
E1103 09:06:47.373823    4647 cacher.go:220] unexpected ListAndWatch error: pkg/storage/cacher.go:163: Failed to list *api.ClusterPolicy: client:
etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured
E1103 09:06:47.374026    4647 cacher.go:220] unexpected ListAndWatch error: pkg/storage/cacher.go:163: Failed to list *api.ClusterPolicyBinding: c
lient: etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured
E1103 09:06:47.374102    4647 cacher.go:220] unexpected ListAndWatch error: pkg/storage/cacher.go:163: Failed to list *api.PolicyBinding: client:
etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured
E1103 09:06:47.374254    4647 cacher.go:220] unexpected ListAndWatch error: pkg/storage/cacher.go:163: Failed to list *api.Group: client: etcd clu
ster is unavailable or misconfigured
E1103 09:06:47.374420    4647 cacher.go:220] unexpected ListAndWatch error: pkg/storage/cacher.go:163: Failed to list *api.Policy: client: etcd cl
uster is unavailable or misconfigured
E1103 09:06:47.376485    4647 reflector.go:203] github.com/openshift/origin/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/plugin/pkg/admission/limitranger/admission.go
:154: Failed to list *api.LimitRange: Get https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8443/api/v1/limitranges?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8443: getsockopt:
connection refused
```

Once the server is started I can login, but the **system** user doesn't seem to have permissions to do very much.  For example the **system** user can't see any project or the services in the cluster.  Running some of the **oc** commands seems to indicate that the **system** user does not have proper permissions as follows:

```
 #./oc login https://localhost:8443 Authentication required for https://localhost:8443 (openshift) Username: system Password: Login
 successful.

 You don't have any projects. You can try to create a new project, by
 running

     oc new-project <projectname>

 # ./oc new-project default 
 Error from server: project "default" already exists
 # ./oc get services --all-namespaces 
 User "system" cannot list all services in the cluster
```

It seems I must be missing something very basic about how to start openshift up from the binary distribution.  I can't find anything in the documentation that seems to speak to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what your environment looks like, so the following might not work 100%.

But can you try the following:

```
oc whoami
oc login -u system:admin
oc whoami
```

the system:admin account is your root account and from their you can create additional user accounts.

The best way that I've found to run a development instance of OpenShift is through oc cluster up. https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/docs/cluster_up_down.md. This runs a containerised version on openshift in docker. Might be worth a spin as it seems that your previous install method has a few errors.

Comment: So using the version that I installed from the tarball I get the following:

Comment: So using the version that I installed from the tarball I get errors when I try to do what you suggest.  First the "oc login -u system:admin" prompts for a password.  I need to use "oc login -u system -p admin " to authenticate.  The list of projects returned is empty.  If I do the "oc cluster up" command I get different responses if I login as "root" or some other user.  Running "oc login -u system:admin" works and returns a proper list of projects, but the web UI still is not returning any projects after login.

Comment: BTW, to install I did the following:

`wget <URL>
tar xvzf openshift-origin-server-v1.3.1-dad658de7465ba8a234a4fb40b5b446a45a4cee1-linux-64bit.tar.gz`

`cd <openshift dir created by tarball>`

`./openshift start`

Comment: @RickBroker You have to create a user (e.g. using htpasswd): https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/configuring_authentication.html#HTPasswdPasswordIdentityProvider and after that authenticate with your system:admin command (in the terminal) and you can give the right policies to your user: https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/configuring_authentication.html#HTPasswdPasswordIdentityProvider

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do this manually (without oc cluster up as mentioned above)

```
export KUBECONFIG=/full/path/to/openshift.local.config/master/admin.kubeconfig

sudo chmod a+rwX -R /path/to/openshift.local.config/

oadm policy add-cluster-role-to-user cluster-admin demo (demigod mode)

oc whoami 
system:admin

oc projects
You have access to the following projects and can switch between them with 'oc project <projectname>':

    default
    kube-system
    openshift
    openshift-infra
  * test
```

this isn't a production setup, this is just for messing around.

p.s.: ignore the errors clusterbinding policy error, the issue is known and doesn't affect you logging in.